# allure-results not getting data: specflow with .net

Tags: .net, visual-studio, specflow, allure

With .net framework 4.7.2 I'm using
SpecFlow.Allure version=3.1.0.6
SpecFlow version=3.3.57

On executing tests from Visual studio in local I'm getting empty allure-results folder getting created.
Not getting any data(json) into this folder

What may be the reason. Appreciate any help/suggestion on this front

Thanks in Advance
Winadi

Comment: Any update on this? Having the same problem here